# Retrieving data from firebase and displaying it in a spinner(Drop down list)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to manually add spinner data to firebase manually,but when i try to display it in a spinner drop down,i get the error:

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.appname.appname.ListItem.

This is my method for retrieving spinner data from firebase and displaying it in a dropdown spinner:

```
 proffRefspin.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e("Spinner Data", "Spinner data is changed!");

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> temp = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot lists : temp){
                Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+lists.getValue().toString());
                list.add(lists.getValue().toString());
                textView.setText(lists.getValue().toString());
            }
            showDataInSpinner(list);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

//displaying data in spinner

```
 public void showDataInSpinner(ArrayList<String> data) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data
    ); //Create the Adapter to set the data
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Set the layout resource to create the drop down views.
    catSpinner.findViewById(R.id.defaultCats);
    catSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); //Set the data to your spinner
}
```

and this is my POJO(ListItem Model)

```
public class ListItem {
    private static final String TAG = "ListItem";
    @Exclude
    String userid;
    private String username,summary,status,details,profession;
    private String imageurl;

    public ListItem(){}



    public ListItem(String username, String summary, String status, String details, String profession, String imageurl) {
        this.username = username;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.status = status;
        this.details = details;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        //this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String id) {
        this.userid = id;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }


    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }




    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageurl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageurl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

When I manually add my list of professions in my firebase db, I get the error. But when the firebase db is empty, there is no error displayed. What am I doing wrong here? I want to be able to display the spinner data from firebase.

This is how im trying to retrieve the data

```
 myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child("Professions").child("profession");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ListItem data = dataSnapshot.getValue(ListItem.class);
            listItems.add(data);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
}
```

**This is the Category Fragment method thats meant to display the professions from firebase:**

```
 private void getFirebaseData() {

    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child("Professions").child("profession");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ProfessionsList data = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfessionsList.class);
            proffItems.add(data);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
}
```

But i am getting the error:
`Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type` com.appname.appname.ListItem.

Image Screenshot to the firebase data structure:
[Firebase Data screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VwhUpV_EtpAGPwRb8daFCfUpzwCFYhmC)

Comment: what are you adding manually?

Comment: I am adding professions as a root node,profession as a child node then inside profession child node:["SoftwareEngineer","Data Scientists"]....

Comment: So i am trying to retrieve this data and display it in a spinner.But my category fragment is rejected the manually added data with the error cannot convert object of string  to.......

Comment: you need to retrieve each one alone, so you do not get that error

Answer (score 0):

get the data from firebase

```
ArrayList<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                categoryList.add(postSnapshot.getValue(Category.class));
            }
            loadDataInSpinner();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

loading data in spinner adapter

```
 private void loadDataInSpinner(){
        categoryArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categoryList);
        spinnerPostCategory.setAdapter(categoryArrayAdapter);
        spinnerPostCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Category category = (Category) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
                spinnerSelectedId= category.getCategoryId();
                spinnerSelectedName = category.getCategoryName();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is Category here the name of the class/Activity?

Comment: Category is model class with category name and category id

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.The main problem i am experiencing is,i want to add data to firebase manually,then display this data in a spinner dropdown list

Comment: you can add data in using firbase syntax as `DatabaseReference databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Category");
        Map<String, Category> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
        categoryMap.put("1", new Category(1, "foo"));
        databaseReference.setValue(categoryMap);`

Comment: Yes,this is the correct way of adding data.But what i am trying to achieve is get a user to select a profession from a dropdown spinner,then based on this selection,the users details are saved under the profession thats got a default ID in firebase.

Comment: I have manually added the list of professions in firebase as:Profession(root node),profession(childnode)and the list of professions under this child node:["Software Engineer","Data Scientist"] ...Software Engineer has a default id of 0,DataScientist has an Id Value of 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  
proffRefspin.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String profession=datas.child("profession").getValue().toString();
          list.add(profession);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list); 
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
    }
});
```

to add only the profession, that you added manually in the database, this way you will have a list of professions in the spinner that the user will be able to select later on. You may have to change the location(`proffRefspin`) depending on where you are adding the `professions`

Change your database to this:

```
Users
 Professions
     randomid
         professionname: software engineer
     randomid
         professionname: data science
```

then do this:

```
  myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child("Professions");
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String prof=dataSnapshot.child("professionname").getValue().toString();
        proffItems.add(prof);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


    }
});
```

Comment: This line is giving errrors:The error is:"Cannot infer arguements Unable to resolve constructer...ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

Comment: I aded activity this:But im still getting an error:"Expression expected".ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserProfileActivity,this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

Comment: @John do: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);`

Comment: Thanks Peter..this works out without an error..but now when i try to display the data from firebase as a list showing the categories,im getting the same error:"Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.appname.appname.ListItem."

Comment: isnt the data getting added in the spinner? Also which data the model class or only the profession you are adding in a list?

Comment: I cant check if the data is being added because the app is crashing when it loads and attempts to display the fragment thats meant to display the list of professions from firebase which i added manually

Comment: Main Activity loads a fragment..Category Fragment...i will add it to my question

Comment: I changed the loading activity from MainActivity to the activity thats meant to display my spinner and the spinner data isnt being loaded to the spinner either

Comment: remove this `ProfessionsList data = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfessionsList.class);` and put this instead `String profession=datas.child("profession").getValue().toString();`

Comment: Thanks Pete,but i already applied this and the spinner does not display the data..this is an image of what the data looks like in firebase:   Heres a link to the ScreenShot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VwhUpV_EtpAGPwRb8daFCfUpzwCFYhmC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169181/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-john).